# How can i write a cron job using a symfony task

Tags: php, symfony1, cron

I'm in the process of creating a automation process to my symfony application which is written as a plugin in symfony.In this plugin i need to add a cron job.now im adding it manually. Can i open cron tab from symfony and write some thing to the cron tab???if so 
i simply run a task and add the cron job from cli.
any suggestions to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to do it from the command line. From a Symfony task you call the system command using the function passthru() from PHP standard.

The following 2 functions  in PHP might help.

```
function mysystem($cmd)
{
  passthru($cmd, $val);
  if ($val != 0)
  {
    mydie("Command $cmd exited with nonzero exit status $val\n");
  }
}

// PHP's die() exits with a happy status, which is useless in scripts
function mydie($s)
{
  fwrite(STDERR, $s);
  exit(1);
}
```

From a script you would do something similar to the following.

- crontab -l | grep -v "the job you are adding" >oldcrontab # remove 
  any duplicate jobs
- echo "cron job you are adding" >>oldcrontab # add the new job
- crontab oldcrontab # reload the crontab

Just use the same strategy, but from PHP using the above functions. That should work.